# Doom emacs meghanada server does not want to start properly

Tags: java, emacs

I am having some weird issues with doom emacs trying to start-up a meghanada server. Here are the logs

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
[INFO ][Main      :  54] use java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-jdk
[INFO ][Main      :  55] use java runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
[INFO ][Main      :  59] use java vm: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
[INFO ][Main      : 151] Meghanada-Server Version:1.3.1-4d1e3bf
[INFO ][GradleProj: 171] loading gradle project:/home/adam/.gradle
[ERROR][EmacsServe: 376] Catching
meghanada.project.ProjectParseException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script '/tmp/1636061032199-0/init13971270568266629877.gradle' (/home/adam/.gradle/caches/6.6/scripts/688xvjsgk5assynnrnjq17dry).
    at meghanada.project.gradle.GradleProject.parseProject(GradleProject.java:229) ~[meghanada-1.3.1.jar:?]
    at meghanada.session.Session.loadProject(Session.java:226) ~[meghanada-1.3.1.jar:?]
    at meghanada.session.Session.findProject(Session.java:139) ~[meghanada-1.3.1.jar:?]
    at meghanada.session.Session.createSession(Session.java:111) ~[meghanada-1.3.1.jar:?]
    at meghanada.session.Session.createSession(Session.java:105) ~[meghanada-1.3.1.jar:?]
    at meghanada.server.emacs.EmacsServer.startServer(EmacsServer.java:361) [meghanada-1.3.1.jar:?]
    at meghanada.Main.main(Main.java:153) [meghanada-1.3.1.jar:?]
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script '/tmp/1636061032199-0/init13971270568266629877.gradle' (/home/adam/.gradle/caches/6.6/scripts/688xvjsgk5assynnrnjq17dry).
    at
```

There are way more logs but I feel like the don't really describe the issue much further so I'll leave them out unless requested to not clutter this post too much.

I am using jdk17 (installed through AUR) and I have also installed gradle to try to see if that would change anything (it didn't)

If any of you have encountered this issue and have found a fix please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

First of all the answer was deeper in the error logs (I am an idiot for ignoring that).

Deeper down I saw

```
unsupported class file major version 61
```

Right away this told me that I am using the wrong version of java.

Downgraded to jdk11 and everything works :)